# different Interpolation techniques

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

what are the differences between spline and Lagrange interpolation, and are there any other kinds that might be similar that perform well ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Lagrange* is a single polynomial, whereas *spline* interpolation is piecewise polynomial (often of cubic degree).

Polynomials are known to be unsuitable for a large number of points, they start oscillating unwieldy. On the other hand, they are infinitely differentiable, offering a maximum degree of continuity.

Reciprocally, (cubic) splines can deal with an arbitrary number of points but offer value, slope and curvature continuity only.

*Hermite* interpolation (*Cardinal* and *Catmull-Rom* splines) is a simple cubic method that can be computed locally, requiring only the knowledge of four points per interval. It provides value and slope continuity.

*Lanczos* interpolation, based on the sinc function, can be used on uniformly sampled data. It performs perfect signal reconstruction in case of a band-limited signal.

Other big names that you will find in the literature (*Bézier*, *B-splines*, *NURBS*) are approximation rather than interpolation methods.

Comment: Polynomials oscillate badly only if you choose the interpolation nodes badly. One place where it's done right is in the Chebfun system. It uses polynomials with degrees in the hundreds without any oscillation problems. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: Also, you can interpolate with Bézier and b-spline curves, of course. Constructing the interpolant requires that you solve a system of linear equations (which is also required by most of the other methods you mentioned).

Comment: @bubba: Bézier and B-splines are polynomials; they won't give you a different result than direct Lagrange or spline interpolation, just extra complexity in construction.

Comment: Sure, the results are the same. In many cases, constructing any kind of globally smooth interpolant involves solving a linear system. Solving in Bézier or b-spline bases is no harder, and offers superior numerical stability. Local interpolants like C-M splines are easier.

Comment: @bubba: the first thing to tell a beginner is that polynomial interpolation is a very unstable process and he shouldn't use, say, above degree 8.